# Можно ли через javascript на сайте обмениваться информацией с человеком?

Tags: javascript, html, данные

Скажем, есть два человека. Один это пользователь. У него есть окошко html со встроенным javscriptом. Ну и там, скажем, есть переменная apple. А у второго человека открыта программа, которая, получив apple от первого человека, отдаст ему peanut. Что за код мне нужно сделать? Как обмениваться данными между именно РАЗНЫМИ программами на РАЗНЫХ компьютерах/ноутбуках?

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью сервера. Javascript отправляет на сервер AJAX запрос, содержащий изменения. У второго пользователя проходит AJAX запрос который получает изменения. Сервер можно написать, например, на python или PHP (А также на других языках). В вашем случае достаточно будет использовать базу данных по типу [supabase](https://supabase.com) или [firebase](https://firebase.google.com)

Comment: На js тоже можно сервер поднять) 
Но тут уже через node.js, а не на клиенте естественно

Comment: @BigCubeCat, можно подробнее?